# How to add custom entitlements to provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, firebase, nativescript, provisioning-profile, entitlements

We are using nativescript, with fastlane and after adding this plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase, we are now having the following error:

[image: XCode error]

We have had to add the additional custom entitlements as shown in the README of the above plugin

```
<key>com.apple.keystore.access-keychain-keys</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.keystore.device</key>
<true/>
```

And this has lead to the error stating that the provisioning profile doesn't include the above entitlements. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your entitlement file name matche your app name (this is basically the folder name of your source code without hyphens or spaces)? Have you placed it inside `App_Resources/iOS`? Did you try a clean build?

Comment: @Manoj thanks for your reply, and yes to all the above

Comment: @Luke Could you fix this problem? I have the same problem and cannot build the application.